# How do you get columns in mysql that has no word greater than 40 characters?

Tags: php, mysql, cpu-word, character

Basically, I'm trying to create a function in php that would give me the most recent column (message) that has no word greater than 40 characters. I was able to get the most recent message but I have no idea how to only get the most recent message that has no word greater than 40 characters. Please refer to the $callrecent variable.

```
<?php
function recentpost($postnum) {
$callrecent = "SELECT message FROM messages WHERE message (HAS NO WORD GREATER THAN 40 CHARACTERS) ORDER BY msg_id DESC LIMIT $postnum,1";

$callrecent_run = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query($callrecent));

$message = stripslashes($callrecent_run['message']);

return $message;
}
?>
```

Comment: You mean `foo 01234567890123456789012345678901234567890 bar` is excluded but `foo 0123456789 0123456789 0123456789 0123456789 0 bar` is included?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand your comment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you could use regular expressions

```
SELECT message
FROM messages
WHERE message not regexp '[[:alnum:]]{41}'
ORDER BY msg_id DESC
LIMIT $postnum, 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
  SELECT message
    FROM messages
   WHERE LENGTH(message) <= 40
ORDER BY msg_id DESC
   LIMIT $postnum, 1
```

Comment: I'm trying to compare the length of each word though and not the length whole string. Nice try though.